# How to remove error mentioned bellow in image white installing shopware with vagrant?

Tags: shopware

I am trying to install Shopware 6 with vagrant but at terminal it gives this error, any solution please.

[image: clike at terminal error]

[image: This is the last part of error]

[image: This comes at the 192.168.33.10, but not the shopware site is appearing]

Comment: This is not the full error message. Please check and add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to use a recent version of Shopware which requires PHP7.4, but your CLI is still running on an older PHP Version - PHP 7.2

[image: marked error message]

Comment: Thank You Alex for your response, but i checked my php version at ubuntu                   
    .PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2021 07:53:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies                                                                                                                 but still its showing same error, could you please tell where I need to upgrade php?

Comment: Try to use 7.4, not 7.2 and not 8.0

Comment: I have upgraded the PHP at local ubuntu 20.04 but when I do vagrant up it shows ubuntu 18.04 at virtual box, I think that ububtu 18.04 has the php7.2 and I am not able to upgrade that. How to upgrade php and ubuntu at virtual box?

Comment: You should be able to specify a newer Ubuntu base image in your Vagrantfile. https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/focal64